# PermissionError 13 when renaming a file just after renaming it

Tags: docker, filesystems, luigi

I am using a luigi context manager that writes to a temporary file and renames it when complete. I am getting "permission denied" errors when it tries to rename the file at the end of the context block.

I thought maybe there was a lock not yet released. So I added a release_lock function that checks the file is available (via renaming it and renaming it back with retries on error). But I am still getting the "permission denied" error.

I am running ubuntu in a docker container and the file is on windows 10 host. The error only happens 1/50 runs.

```
        with self.output().temporary_path() as f:
           createfile()
           release_lock(f)
```

Comment: Can you please copy/paste the error? Also, check if you can `ls` the file.

Comment: Can't paste it as it has gone for now (it will no doubt be back). From memory it was: PermissionError (error 13) Permission Denied.... yes I can ls the file. In fact my release lock function renames it and renames it back to make sure it exists and is available. And manually I can rename the file and just carry on. And I have run the same task many times and it works fine 99% of the time.

Comment: I have had issues with luigi when the RAM runs out of memory, but it yields a different error then. Also, I have made the mistake of trying to read / write files which I have no access to, but again those I cannot ls usually. So if you have checked both these things, I am not sure what else it may be. Generally I make sure I can do the job without luigi first, to make sure all is smooth and the error is not luigi related.

Comment: I have run over a thousand similar jobs using Luigi and the same task. 99% of the time it works fine. Just occasionally it gets this error. I suspect it is a RAM issue or some other resource issue rather than the file. I added a retry loop that renames the folder and renames back. Still fails so I suspect it is something else.

Comment: My biggest issue was RAM especially when applying multiple workers, so maybe try monitoring this. Or overload the RAM purposely to see the error.